# I wrote this code to print an integer in decimal taken as user input, but I can't understand what step is wrong?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, dos

```
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 100H
.DATA
    MSG1 DB " Enter first number  : ",0Ah,0Dh,'$'
    MSG2 DB " The number is: ",0ah,0dh,'$'
.CODE
   MAIN PROC
        MOV AX,@DATA
        MOV DS,AX
        LEA DX,MSG1
        MOV AH,09H
        INT 21H

    L1:  
        MOV AH,01H
        INT 21H
        XOR AH,AH
        CMP AL,13
        JE L2
        MOV DX,0H
        MOV DX,AX
        ADD DX,30H
        PUSH DX
        JMP L1

    L2:
        LEA DX,MSG2
        MOV AH,09H
        INT 21H

    L3: POP DX
        MOV AH,02H
        INT 21H
    LOOP L3

        MOV AH,4CH
        INT 21H
        END MAIN
    MAIN ENDP
```

Comment: Try debugging the program. It's small enough that you can go line by line. (I would focus on the `loop` instruction.)

Comment: ok.thanks for your input.

Comment: I'm more like "which step is correct actually"... For a start, to make it not trash the stack, you have to pair every `push` with `pop`. Check `LOOP` instruction description. Also it's not clear what you are doing with the value from input, maybe you can try to check each instruction, what it does, and comment your intentions, none of that makes much sense except `push dx`. (and for sure check it in debugger, so you can verify you understand each instruction's effect correctly)

Comment: if you (in L1) count up CX with each value you push, you had a defined loop count in L3. And don't forget to set CX to zero before you count. BTW: pop gives the values back in reversed order than you pushed them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intake part has many superfluous instructions and fails to count the number of `PUSH`'s that you do.

> ```
> L1:  
>     MOV AH,01H
>     INT 21H
>     XOR AH,AH         <<< Superfluous
>     CMP AL,13
>     JE L2
>     MOV DX,0H         <<< Superfluous
>     MOV DX,AX         <<< Superfluous
>     ADD DX,30H        <<< Superfluous
>     PUSH DX
>     JMP L1
> ```

This is a better version:

```
    XOR CX,CX      <<< This you need
L1:  
    MOV AH,01H
    INT 21H        <<< gives AL
    CMP AL,13
    JE L2
    PUSH AX        <<< AL is already a character! No need to add 30H.
    INC CX         <<< This you need
    JMP L1
```

---

To use the `LOOP` instruction you need to setup the CX register beforehand (see above). In case no number was inputted, CX will be zero, so you have to test for it:

```
    JCXZ L4
L3:
    POP DX         <<< DL is a character
    MOV AH,02H
    INT 21H
    LOOP L3
L4:
    MOV AH,4CH
    INT 21H
```

---

As @Tommylee2k already remarked, the output will be in reverse. This is probably not your intention. However to get that right, using the stack is not the optimal solution. Better use a simple memory buffer.

Comment: Thanks for your help.Hugely appreciated.